# How can I read and write from/to a JSON file in a github pages repo?

Tags: javascript, json, github-pages

Preface: I'm a novice programmer at best.
I'm trying to make a github pages page and I'd like it to store some data on a JSON within the same repo. All it needs to do is wait for a button press on the webpage and then increment a value in the JSON file, then write the new value to the JSON in the repo.

testCounter.html which contains the script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<button>Increment</button>
<br>
<div id="counter">...</div>

<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    for(;;){
        var counterJSON = JSON.parse(/*get json file here*/);
        //update the number shown on the page
        //check for button click
        counterJSON.counter++;
        //write updated JSON file
    }
</script>
```

testJSON.json which contains the data for the counter

```
{"counter": 0}
```

I'd like any user with the page open to see it continuously update even if they didn't click the button, thus the infinite loop. Any time the button is clicked, the number should be increased by 1 and written to the JSON file.

Comment: also once you get hosting.. your idea of all visitors of your page hammering the server `for(;;)`, you soon rethink the usefulness of the code.

Comment: I’d consider using GitHub’s built-in API or a serverless backend (like Firebase) to handle data storage. Create an API endpoint to handle increments and store your data there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Github Pages is designed for hosting simple static websites and supports no form of server-side code, so there is no means to do this which is either trivial or doesn't have other issues.

Github does have an [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) so you could possibly build a single page application which allows someone to OAuth against Github and then issue a pull request which updates the counter when you approve it. This is unlikely to be practical for your needs.

You should find a hosting service more suitable to your needs.